# “Generalized” Fourier transform

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

When solving boundary value problems, I know that a lot of the time a solution can be found using an eigenfunction expansion, where the eigenfunctions are discrete. I am wondering if there is a similar theory for operators which have continuous eigenfunctions. To be precise, I’m trying to justify that given a continuous spectrum of eigenfunctions $\psi_f$ of an operator
f, a function $\Psi$ may be written as
$$\Psi(x)=\int a_f \psi_f(x) df$$
where the $\psi_f$ are “normalized” such that
$$\int |a_f|^2df = 1$$
and
$$a_f=\int \Psi(x)\psi_f^*(x)dx$$
That statement is taken out of a quantum mechanics textbook and I am trying to find the mathematical theory which makes it precise. Any explanation or reference recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way of making this rigorous is via so-called 'rigged Hilbert spaces', e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43519/55641. In particular this makes expressions like $|x\rangle$ rigorous when they're usually more like suggestive notation. The nLab wiki page for [rigged Hilbert space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigged+Hilbert+space) may also be interesting (if incomplete).

Comment: In the continuous case, you don't typically get normalizable eigenfunctions $\psi_f$, such as with the exponentials or $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform is one such example. However, the eigenfunctions are not normalizable, even though integrals of them are normalization. If $L=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, then $L\psi_s = s\psi_s$ where $\psi_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{isx}$. However $\psi_s(x)$ is not normalizable on $(-\infty,\infty)$ even though integrals with respect to the parameter $s$ are integrable:
$$
                \psi(x)=\int_a^b a(s)\psi_{s}(x)ds
$$
This function is square integrable if the coefficient function $a$ is square integrable, and
$$
            \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x)|^2dx=\int_a^b|a(s)|^2ds.
$$
This is justified using properties of the Fourier transform.